# View of taxonomies connected to view of each taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I'm creating a store using Drupal commerce and I'm trying to show a catalog of products.

1. First I create taxonomy of product types
2. Then I use taxonomy to create a view of product types(product type
   view) and I'm showing taxonomies image
3. Then I add a taxonomy reference field to product contents

I want to show all products of a type every time I click on a taxonomy in product type catalog view.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use “Contextual filters” in view and
Add the filters: “Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution yo can get the result with some struggle, but I have a better solution for you.
Create a list that show all product in categories. (If you do not need this,  skip this step.)

- Create a view of product type
- Add a relation to category (taxonomy you used in product display)
- Add a taxonomy field (also images)
- Group the result by category

Create a view with  path something like `product/*` and pass the category ID to it.

then add contextual filter on your category field,and get default value from the URL.

for getting better involve with views contextual filter read [this article](http://dannyenglander.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7).
if you need more details tell me to provide it.